# Rectangle start fixed at top center animates to full screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-transitions

I am trying to animate a small rectangular div that is centered/fixed at the top of the screen and will scale from the center into a full screen overlay. Here is a wireframe of the animation I am trying to create.

[image]

I have a solution now but it is definitely not the most clean or elegant:

```html
<div class="step1"></div>
```

```css
.step1 {
  border:none;
  background:none;
  text-align: Center;
  font-size: 1.6em;
  height: 200px;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: blue;
  position: fixed;
  left: 47%;
  margin-left: -1.75em;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  transition: all .2s;
}

.step2 {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0%;
  top: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border:none;
  background:none;
  color: white;
  text-align: Center;
  background-color: blue;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  border-radius: 0;
}
```

I am also getting a janky animation and I know there must be a better way. Can anyone offer a cleaner solution?

Comment: Where is your solution? can you please update snippet with your solution

Comment: How exactly do you trigger the animation?

Comment: I'm using React, so it would have been really difficult to copy all the code. It's just a simple toggle class though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `.toggleClass()` on `.click()`:

```js
$('div').click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('step');
});
```

```css
div {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%); /* makes it horizontally centered */
  background: blue;
  transition: all .3s linear; /* added linear transition effect, it's "ease" by default */
}

.step {
  width: 100vw; /* 100% of the viewport width */
  height: 100vh; /* 100% of the viewport height */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using css animations like so

```css
.step1 {
  border:none;
  background:none;
  text-align: Center;
  font-size: 1.6em;
  height: 200px;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: blue;
  position: fixed;
  left: 47%;
  margin-left: -1.75em;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  transition: all .2s;
  animation-name:demo;
  animation-duration:2s;
  animation-fill-mode:forwards;
}

@keyframes demo{
  0%{height:200px;width:300px;left:47%;margin-left:-1,75em}
  100%{height:100%;width:100%;left:0;margin-left:0}
}
```

```html
<div class="step1"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my approach. You trigger the animation by hovering over the div.  I decided to use transition because It's more practical for simple applications like this.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<style type="text/css">
 div {
background-color: #ff0000;
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
background: red;
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
left: 50%;
transition: width 10s, height 10s,  left 10s;

}
div:hover {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
left: 0;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the following demo:

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    $('#myDiv').toggleClass('step1 step2');
  },1000);
});
```

```css
#myDiv {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;  
  background-color: blue;
  transition: all .2s;
}

.step1 {
  left: 35%;
  right: 35%;
  height: 100px;
}

.step2 {
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: auto;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myDiv" class="step1"></div>
```

Comment: Exactly what I need structurally but the animation needs to be more fluid.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an easy solution:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
}

div {
  width: 300px;
  margin: auto;
  height: 200px;
  background: blue;
  animation: animate 3s linear 1s forwards;
}

@keyframes animate {
  to {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```